# How to Apply Run time localization for Storyboard and NIB files without using IBOutlets?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Is it possible to Apply localization from within the application for Storyboard / NIB files?

Comment: I don't understand how localisation (internationalisation) and `IBOutlet`s are related?  Please clarify.

Comment: IBOutlet of UI controls used in NIB files.

Comment: Yeah I know what they are, but not what they have to do with your question.